# Django: a model instance for every possible combination of 2 other model instances

Tags: python, django, database, model

I have a user model with a Foreignkey indicating to which group a user belongs. A user can order a service. The price of the service depends on which service it is and to which group the user belongs. The number of services and groups can be changed, but at all times I need a price for each possible service-group combination.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.Foreignkey(Group)

class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField()

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreignkey(User)
    type = models.Foreignkey(Service)

class Service(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()
```

Seems like I can't simply add a price field to the Service model because there are as many prices for the same service as there are groups.

**Question 1:** In what kind of model should I store the prices?
I was thinking of the following:

```
class Price(models.Model):
    service = models.Foreignkey(Service)
    group = models.Foreignkey(Group)
    price = models.DecimalField()
```

Would that be a sensible strategy?

**Question 2**: Only an Admin will create a new group or service, but when that happens I need to ensure that somehow in Django's admin interface when for example a new service is created, the form also asks for different prices for each group and vice versa if a new group is created the form should also ask prices for all services. On top of that it would probably be best to ensure that there can be only one Price instance for each unique service-group combination.

Comment: Are the different prices always derivable as a formula? e.g. if group 1, *5. price, if group 2,  *2 price?

Comment: @gregory I see your point, if there is a fixed formula behind it you could store the price in the Service model and a factor in the Group model making the problem trivial. But lets say no, the prices can be completely arbitrary

Comment: Ok, then yes, your Price class is quite sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 2, I'd require the prices in the new group (or service) form to be set. You can use a required drop down field, that is populated with a query of prices. A sketch of the group form may exemplify the point:

```
class groupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, empty_label=None, required=True)
    ...
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(groupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['price'].queryset = self.instance.price_set.all()
```